# Is n/2 time complexity worth it?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Say I have the task of pushing all the odd integers between two given points into an array. The first thing most people would think of would be to just iterate from point a to point b with a mod check to push into the array.
Given a large enough data set, would the following actually provide an advantage or would it be completely unnecessary?

```
findOddNums(start, end){
  let output = []
  let iter = start
  if(start%2 > 0) {
    output.push(start)
    iter+=2
  }else iter++

  while(iter<=end){
    output.push(iter)
    iter+=2
  }
  return output
}
```

Comment: unlikely but benchmark...................O(N/2) = O(N) as N -> infinity....

Comment: There is no such thing as *"n/2 time complexity"*. `O(...)` is a set containing multiple functions. The set for `O(n)` is the same as the set for `O(n/2)`. Both are contained in the same set, the set of linear functions. Usually people denote the set by just `O(n)`.

Comment: Everytime you ask yourself if something is actually faster in practice you **must** measure it. There is no way around. It's hard to estimate runtime with little knowledge of the project and all effects like CPU and compiler optimizations and stuff. You must measure it.

Comment: If you change "every odd number" to "every number which is 1 mod 3" and then "1 mod 4" and then... eventually you will arrive a modulus which makes the loop faster. So it's probably worth doing in a library.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking it would be O(d/2) where d is the distance between your endpoints (end-start). Why d/2? Because there're as many even numbers as odd numbers in a range (+-1), so you start with the first odd you find and iterate in steps of 2 from there. So O(n/2) is not good, O(d/2) is.

Comment: `O(d/2)` is usually denoted by `O(d)`, the set of linear functions.

Comment: true, I meant big-theta, but I don't have big-theta in my keyboard :)

Comment: Yeah. But that doesn't matter. It's still the set of linear functions. `Theta(d)` then.

Comment: Hahah ok, you win.

Comment: Let me continue a bit: `d` linearly depends on `n`, so it's still `O(n)` :)

Comment: @blade: &Theta; will work in a post (but not a comment). Although you can copy and paste it from a post to a comment like this: Θ.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yeah, processing every other item will be less work than processing every single item. Consider this code:

```
for (int x = start; x <= end; ++x)
{
    if (x % 2 != 0)
    {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

As opposed to:

```
start = (start + 1) - (start % 2);
for (int x = start; x <= end; x += 2)
{
    // do whatever
}
```

The second is going to do half as many iterations of the loop, which means you don't have to execute that pesky conditional. And since there's no conditional there, you're going to get a huge win in branch prediction on modern processors.

That said, I doubt that it'll be a huge overall win, because the most expensive part is pushing the elements into the other array, and you do that the same number of times either way.

It's still O(n) complexity, though: the number of iterations increases linearly with the size of n. n in this case being the difference between start and end.